# Maven surefire fails on install but not on package phase with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: maven, surefire

I've got a strage problem.

When I build my maven project like this:

`mvn clean package` *it compiles and successfully runs the unit tests* but when I do

`mvn clean install` *it still compiles, reports build success but shows this strange error:*

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/BarClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at com.foo.BarTest.shouldTestSomething(BarTest.java:35)
```

I've got maven 3.0.4, surefire-plugin-version 2.14, junit 4.11
Here are representative parts of my `pom.xml`

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>               
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.14</version>
                </plugin>
         </pluginManagement>
</build>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've played with changing surefire/junit versions as well with surefire's `<useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>` but still got the problem.

I really don't understand the cause of the `NoClassDefFound` error ...
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I fixed the messy problem: 

 I also had `cobertura` plugin running (like any quality software project has :), that instrumented the classes thus triggering a recompile, thus a re-run of unit-tests hence the strange `NoClassDefError`

Huh, what a busy day!

Comment: So how did you finally solve this issue? I just inherited a complex maven project with a similar setup, which exhibits a similar NoClassDefFoundError for some cases. I tried disabling the Cobertura plugin, but still get this error...

Comment: @GyroGearless Just disabling cobertura plugin worked for me. You can set maven output to debug(really verbose) and look for abnormal things like duplicate compilation aso. It should point you in the right direction to solve your problem.